# MYSQL comparing date columns with timestamp columns

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp

I have a timestamp column in one table, and two date columns in another table. Is it ok to compare them without the the "Date()" function?

table A has column created_on timestamp
table B has columns effective_date date, and expiry_date date

Is it ok to do:

```
select * from A,B 
WHERE created_on between effective_date and expiry_date
```

or do I need to do:

```
select * from A,B 
WHERE date(created_on) between effective_date and expiry_date
```

Also which is better in terms of performance (if both are good)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you compare date `date(created_on) between effective_date and expiry_date` is better because date compare is faster than datetime compare

Comment: you mean timestamp ? sorry, what does compression have to do with select query?

Comment: sorry i mean compare @user2075371